# how to create a standard information attribute for a file in ntfs

Tags: c

I have a usb formatted with NTFS.I need to create a file using 'C' so I want to know

1. How to allocate a free entry for my file after reading $BITMAP
   attribute of mft file.
2. How to create attributes($STANDARD
   INFORMATION and $FILENAME ATTRIBUTE) for my file.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be using the normal file creation function calls?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:The re framed question would be steps to create a file when programming embedded usb host where in the host tries to create a file in a peripheral device attached to it. I have to be creating my own lib to read and write.

Comment: If I'm understanding your reframed question correctly, you're asking us to advise you on how to create a file on an embedded system where there is no operating system support for creating files on USB devices.  I don't think you've given enough information in the question for anyone to be able to help you; the answer will depend entirely on the o/s for (which you're writing the program) and what primitives it provides.  If it doesn't provide any file creation primitives, you're presumably going to have to write them yourself.  The result will be very platform specific.

Comment: OK if want to know generally how to create file(complete algorithm) in ntfs file system without using library functions of any OS how will I have to do it? I am using omap3530 evm where i am not using any o/s and interrupts in my coding . I have finished ohci controller programming for host controller and my next step would be create a file in the attached usb device and write something in the created file,create an attributes(mentioned in the prior question).How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

So I realize I am a few years late to the party but having actually done something like this successfully I will offer what worked for me.

[flatcap - NTFS Documentation](https://flatcap.org/linux-ntfs/ntfs/)
 -> This is about the best documentation I have found save for [File System Forensics Analysis by Brian Carrier](http://www.campus64.com/digital_learning/data/cyber_forensics_essentials/info_file_system_forensic_analysis.pdf)

The big difference between what I was doing and what you are trying to do is I was reconstituting deleted files not creating new ones.  So I had the major advantage of being able to use copied attributes with minor alterations.  Here are some of my findings.

New file records need $Standard_Information (0x10) $Filename (0x30) $Security_Descriptor (0x50) and $Data (0x80) attributes.  You can get away without the Security_Descriptor if you index the file in the $Secure system file but I recommend using the $Security_Descriptor for backwards compatibility and simplicity, also this is how linux ntfs-3g does it (I learned a lot from observing ntfs-3g's changes to parts of file system using git's difftool). You Can just copy the $Security_Descriptor from an example file with the same permissions that you want.  You can copy the basic structure of the other attributes as well from a similar file and make the following alterations:

- $Standard_Information and $Filename need new timestamps.  You also need to update the File Altered and MFT Altered $Standard_Information timestamps (the middle 2) in the file record of the parent directory, and all of these timestamps should match.
- $Data is pretty simple.  You just need to make sure you specify the correct length of the data if resident, if non-resident which most data is you are going to need to read up on data runs from flatcap.
- $Filename should just need a new name length and attribute length to match the new name.
- The File Record Header (first 24 bytes or so) needs to be given the correct file record size padded to an 8 byte boundary and a seq number of 1 if the file record is brand new (otherwise it needs to be incremented by 1 if it is being reallocated).
- It is extremely important that whenever you update anything that has a USN (File and Index Records) that you update it and swap the end of each sector with the USN and into the Update Sequence Array.  I am not sure how much you are supposed to increment it but I wrote my code to increment it for each sector that was written and that seemed to work.

You are going to need to read up on Index Records in order to properly place your file in a parent directory:

- Make sure you insert the corresponding Index Entry key for your new file into the correct index record or node of the directory B*tree.
- The index record USN needs to be updated as does its length and the timestamps in its self-referential key.

In regards to dealing with the $Bitmap attribute of the $MFT. I am not positive how NTFS does this and will update when I learn more, but here is what I did. It is important to realize that NTFS has an MFT reserve of low numbered file records that are not to be written to unless the volume is under stress, and that if you write to the wrong record windows will find your new file to be corrupt.

- You do not need to update the USN
- Each bit represents a file record.
- Find the last (not first) full file record and pick the first empty one after that.
- Fill in the bit and record the MFT File Reference Address in the index entry representation of your new file.
- Write your new file record to that location.

MFT File Reference Addresses are a compound of a 48 bit File Reference number (you found in $Bitmap) that is nothing other than an index of records in the $MFT ( 0 is the first record, etc) and a 16 bit Sequence Number (found in the file record header)  The File Reference Number can be used to find any file record by first parsing the $Data attribute of the $MFT File Record and then counting the records one by one until you reach that number (obviously you wouldn't actually need to count them one by one with some simple math, but I feel how to do that will become clearer when you read up on Data Runs).

There is a probably a ton of stuff I forgot, but I kind of wish someone had written some of this down when I started researching because then My life might have been the tinyest bit easier.